How to Retrieve All Commit IDs After a Merge in GitHub
I have a GitHub repository with a branch named feature1 that contains 10 commits. A pull request (PR) has been raised to merge feature1 into the stage branch. Once the PR is merged, I want a GitHub Actions pipeline to run and list all commit hashes that were present in the feature1 branch.
I attempted to use the following code to achieve this, but it is displaying incorrect commit hashes, which do not match those in the feature1 branch
Could someone help me correct this approach? How can I accurately retrieve all commit hashes from feature1 after the PR has been merged to stage?
name: stage deployment Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - stage

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}

      - name: List commits in PR
        id: list-commits
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN_GITHUB }}
        run: |
          pr_number=${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
          commits=$(gh pr view $pr_number --json commits --jq '.commits[].oid')
          echo "Commit hashes from stage branch:"
          echo "$commits"
          echo "$commits" > commit-hashes.txt

      - name: Save commits to artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: commit-hashes
          path: commit-hashes.txt


The workflow trigger is push but you're using github.event.pull_request in your workflow. See Running your pull_request workflow when a pull request merges.

Also, lint your workflow with https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ for other potential issues.

you can get all the commits using git log main..$MERGED_BRANCH_NAME --oneline
name: List Commits from Merged Branch

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  list-commits:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: List commits from merged branch
      run: |
        # Fetch all branches and tags
        git fetch --all

        # Get the name of the merged branch (assuming the branch name is passed as an input)
        MERGED_BRANCH_NAME="feature-branch"

        # List all commits from the merged branch
        git log main..$MERGED_BRANCH_NAME --oneline

But I suggest you to add a workflow dispatch event for above workflow by passing name of the feature branch as input.

Its not working and it is not listing commit hashes , This is the output:  * [new branch]      stage      -> origin/stage
